# Mail client that scrapes and sends incomming emails from gmail web panel instead of using API

Tags: email-client

My company's IT department forbids the use of Thunderbird but instead forces me to use Gmail's web panel.

Therefore I am looking for a tool that logs-in and scrapes any incoming email from the web panel. Also, I would like to be able to send using the client instead of a browser. Is there a FOSS mail client that is able to do it in Linux?